# Context Menu Colors

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu, themes

When I right click a program on the start bar the context menu has a black background after the separator. Is there a way to make this menu transparent or at least reduce the difference in color between the black and grey?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Context Menu Colors]

Comment: it's not very clear what is the desired state that you want. Do you want to just change the color? Do you want it to be transparent? or match your theme? Please clarify

Comment: It's really really dark. I *think* it used to be transparent before I updated but really I just don't want such a stark contrast between the grey and black.

Comment: I've tried changing colors, transparencies, themes, but nothing changes the color of the context menu. I don't think it was different before.

Comment: here is a link to my friends, as you can see it's not as dark. https://i.gyazo.com/21b07ea903d302360caa53d2069361f1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to windows 10 changed the way it looks.

Other than reverting the update I can't find a way to revert back to the previous look.